# Doctrine: restrict to natural number

Tags: doctrine, numbers

is it possible to add a restriction via Doctrine annotation to force a number attribute to be always equal or greater than 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Either change the datatype to `unsigned` using the following annotation:

```
@ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
```

That will alter the type to `unsigned` (zero and up). I'm not sure it is supported on all DBAL platforms but I'm sure MySQL supports it.

Or, if you use [Symfony Validator Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThanOrEqual.html):

```
// src/Acme/SocialBundle/Entity/Person.php
namespace Acme\SocialBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Person
{
    /**
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(
     *     value = 18
     * )
     */
    protected $age;
}
```

The above example forces the `age` property to be 18 or higher.